# the method setmessage is undefined for the type main activity

Tags: android

I'm just learning how to build apps and I'm using android apps for absolute beginners. In one of the tutorials it asks me to write the code below, but I get the error:

```
setMessage(string) is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

Now the code is written exactly as it says in the book. Any help would be much appreciated,

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem Item) {
    RelativeLayout bkgr = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.UiDesigns);
    final
    ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick an Image!");
   .setMessage("Please Select Image One or Image Two:")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("IMAGE 1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("IMAGE 2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
builder.setTitle("Pick an Image!");
```

Should just be:

```
builder.setTitle("Pick an Image!")
```

(no ';'), so that the next line tags onto it correctly.

Comment: NICE ONE THANKS SOMETIMES THESE BOOKS ARE NOT 100% CORRECT, HOWEVER IM STILL GETTING THE ERROR SYNTAX ERROR ON TOKENS IN MY JAVA FILE

Comment: public static final int image 1 or 2=0x7f050008; THIS IS WHERE MY ERROR IS THANKS IT IS ASKING ME TO DELETE  THESE TOKENS

Comment: @ppx100 Could you post this issue as a separate question with the relevant code please? Then it will be much easier for people to help you.